# Python Code Mysql Connection String from text file

Tags: python, mysql

I am fetching data from  MySql Database using python and it works well. Now I would like to read the connection string details(host="192.168.1.50", user="dbuser", passwd="password", db="dbTest") from a text file. I tried my best but it is not working. Can anyone please help with a sample code.. Thanks in  advance... Here is my code...

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.1.50", user="dbuser", passwd="password", db="dbTest")
sql_insert_query = "SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 from dbTest.tbllog"
cursor = connection.cursor()
result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: Basically you want to store all the credentials in a text file and read it when you have to make connection?

Comment: use `f =open('filename.txt','r')` to open a file in read mode and then you can read the lines by `lines=f.readlines()` now the `lines` will have all the lines from file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Saurav Panda... I have tried this below code, but it is not working.. def readConnectionString():
    global conn_str
    file = open("connectionstring.txt","r")
    conn_str = file.read()
    #print(conn_str)
    file.close()

connection = MySQLdb.connect(conn_str)
sql_insert_query = "SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 from dbTest.tbllog"
cursor = connection.cursor()
result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query)
connection.commit()

Comment: can you post your file content?

Comment: Dear  CaffeinatedCod3r, Here is the file content....  host="192.168.1.50", user="dbuser", passwd="password", db="dbTest"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `eval()` function:

```
inp = open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')

connection = eval('MySQLdb.connect({})'.format(inp.readline().strip()))

inp.close()
```

Please note that if the structure of the file will change this code won't work. Also, remember about importing the required library.